# Trying to write output file but not getting any data in output file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to write output file but not getting any output in file.Using below code I am not able to write the data in output file. Please check my code: In this script i am trying to do some bioinformatics analysis. 
1. The first line contains the name of the protein and the count of subsequent lines of output for this protein (say N)
2. Each of the next N lines contains a match information: the locations of the GBoxes and the actual matches (remember there are perturbations and X's, i.e. wild cards, that are allowed).

I am getting expected output but not able to write output data in file.

**Script**

```
def write_file(data):

    file_name = r'C:\Users\Vishnu\Desktop\Hiral_project_analysis\output_1.txt'
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as x_file:
        x_file.write('{}'.format(data))

def run():
    data = H(protein,x1,x2,x3,x4, protein_name)
    write_file(data)
```

Comment: Did you try tracing (usually using `print`) the value of `data` in `run()` after calling `H()`?  Note that you call `H()` in the `for` loop without capturing the return value, then you call `run()` which also calls `H()` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should get your indentations right (if it's not a copy&paste problem here).

Second: Why are you calling `H()` before `run()`? `H()` is also called inside `run()`.

Third: `H()` does not have any return value. You assign the return value to `data` in `run()` but there is no such return value. I guess you want to add `return candidates` at the end of your function `H()`.

Fourth: You should use `'a'` instead of `'wb'` as file opening mode since you want to append every single line instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Dear Can you please explain me with example? I am new in python

Comment: @vishnu:  the explanation in this answer should be clear to anyone who has written the code you show. If you don't know about `return` or file opening modes then you should follow a basic python tutorial.

Comment: Good. Then you should accept the answer as solution.

Comment: @lebenlechzer, Dear Can you please suggest me how to save multiple graphs in output directory ?